# Creating a Facebook App [Newbie]

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-app-requests

i'm kinda new to this field. I'm about to create a facebook app and I don't know exactly how to.
I need a little tut and codes for the app. I'm so appreciate if you can help me. :) 
This is how I want it.

- A photo uploading app that anyone can give permission to app and upload photos to facebook from another web site by clicking a button "Upload to Facebook" simply.
- that app must automatically create a new Photo Album on facebook at the 1st photo upload by user with an album name and description which decided by the app admin.
- every photo captions must be edited auto as "Original Caption + Text decide by app admin"

That's all. I think you understand what I mean and what i'm going to do with. :)
Somebody Help me please.......!!!

Comment: This sounds more like a request for code rather than help guiding. Please consider showing what work you have done so far on the app. It's not fair to you or to us as developers do your work for you. [facebook-app-requests] is not the proper tag to use for requests for code also. Please consider re-reading our [FAQ]

Answer (score 4):

start from the beginning, i.e., by reading the Getting Started tutorial from FB.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/

Answer (score 0):

Try Spring Social Library. It has support for FB Twitter Linked In etc. That's easy to go for.

Comment: How can I use that?
Please i'm a newbie on this matter.